# Android Seek Bar Saved Preferences

Tags: android, seekbar

Hi there I am trying to get an integer that will be given by a SeekBar using the .getprogress to go into an Integer which will get saved by the preference and will go to my toast code at another side of my application to make things easier heres my code already.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import tk.mizzeeboy.freestorageconverter.R;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity{

    SeekBar cl;
    TextView t;
    String lolly , finlly;
    int hehe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.333);

        cl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekB3r1);
        t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textV3w1);

        cl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                t.setTextSize((cl.getProgress()) * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
                hehe = cl.getProgress(); 
                finlly.valueOf(hehe);

                SharedPreferences mypreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("TeamName", finlly);
                editor.commit();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

and in my other activity I want to open and read it heres the code for that

```
SharedPreferences mypreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
              String teamnamestring = mypreferences.getString("TeamName", "Please Enter :)"); 
            Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(BitActivity.this, teamnamestring , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            andEggs.show();
```

But my problem is that it I am getting the Please Enter Sign everytime and it will not pick up my integer can someone help?

Comment: You set the integer value and trying to get string value?

Comment: oh yes I think I see it but I cannot set it to integer and get it work

Comment: so when you are saving call putString,

Comment: i dont get what u mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What TGMCians is saying is that you put `hehe` as `Int` in the preferences (`editor.putInt("TeamName", hehe);),` in first Activity then get it as `String` in the other Activity (`mypreferences.getString("TeamName",...`). This will cause `ClassCastException`. Either, you put it as a `String` from the begining or get it as an `Int` in the second Activity.

Try:

```
    int val=mypreferences.getInt("TeamName",-1);
String teamnamestring="";
if(val==-1){
teamnamestring="Please Set Up Your Custom Text Size!";}
else {teamnamestring=String.ValueOf(val);}

Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(BitActivity.this, teamnamestring , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            andEggs.show();
```

Comment: but then where do I put the int val=mypreferences.getInt("TeamName"); ?

Comment: ok I replaced (mypreferences.getString("TeamName",...) with int val=mypreferences.getInt("TeamName");  and im still getting an error under .getInt

Comment: You still set the default value to a String and you put the integer value in makeText(). Check the update. If you still get Exception, please post your LogCat